# Pacman Full system upgrade failure

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade, pacman

I'm trying to do a full system upgrade using pacman on ArchLinux. I have kernel 3.2.

When typing `sudo pacman -Syu`
I got the following errors

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
core is up to date
extra is up to date
community is up to date
:: Starting full system upgrade...
error: could not parse package description file 'libice-1.0.8-1/desc' from db 'extra'
resolving dependencies...
warning: cannot resolve "p11-kit>=0.12", a dependency of "gnutls"
warning: cannot resolve "vim-runtime=7.3.495-1", a dependency of "gvim"
:: The following packages cannot be upgraded due to unresolvable dependencies:
      gnutls  gvim

Do you want to skip the above packages for this upgrade? [y/N] y
looking for inter-conflicts...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: nvidia: requires linux<3.3
```

I've tried to reinstall libice but I got the following error

```
error: could not parse package description file 'libice-1.0.8-1/desc' from db 'extra'
warning: libice-1.0.8-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for inter-conflicts...
error: failed to prepare transaction (package filename is not valid)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try running `pacman -Syy` before update.

Comment: @diffycat Already did it

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are using a mirror that's (way) out of sync.

The `p11-kit`, `vim-runtime` packages have been updated on 2012-04-01 and 2012-04-10 respectively. The nvidia package has been updated today (2012-04-11), so all you need to do is wait a while.

It's quite interesing that you have a `linux` package version 3.3, though and a `gvim` package from 2012-04-10. Did you change repositories (disabled `testing`) or mirrors lately?
You might want to use the [mirrorlist](https://www.archlinux.org/mirrors/status/) or [mirrorlist updater](https://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist/) to find an up-to-date mirror near you. This would most likely also repair your `extra` db file.

Comment: I don't know what I've done, but it seems to work now. Maybe a problem with my internet connection that was too slow.